# Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch() on boolean in

Tags: php, pdo

помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с ошибкой кода. Я повторяла пример из книги PHP7 в подлиннике.
1.Код соединения с Базой данных  connect.php

```
<?php
try {
$pdo = new PDO ('mysql:host=localhost; dbname = kinoplay', 'root', ''); 
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Невозможно установить соединение с базой данных";
}

?>





2.Извлечение данных при помощи PDO
require_once("connect.php");
$query = "SELECT * FROM catalog";
$cat = $pdo->query($query);

       try {
        while($catalog = $cat->fetch())echo $catalog['name']."<br />";
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Ошибка выполнения запроса: ". $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: [php fetch boolean](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=php+fetch+boolean)

Comment: перед тем как задать вопрос  соотвественно пошарила интернет не остался без внимания и данный сайт, но нет конкретного ответа с указанием на ошибку, ибо ответы ссылкой на другие темы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Call to a member function fetch() on boolean in` - это **вторичная** ошибка, вызванная проблемой при выполнении SQL запроса. Чтобы получить настоящее сообщение об ошибке, надо соответствующим образом настроить PDO.

К сожалению, пример из книги очень устарел, в нем почти все неправильно. И в первую очередь нормальное информирование об ошибках. В примере отсутствуют нужные элементы, и наоборот, добавлен бессмысленный код, который ничего не делает.

#### 1. Код соединения с Базой данных `connect.php`

Правильный код можно взять [отсюда](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/connect_to_mysql). В частности, там объясняется одна из ошибок, допущенных в этом коде. в DSN не должно быть никаких украшений - пробелов, лишних кавычек и прочего. А вот что обязательно должно быть - это указание **кодировки**, в которой мы хотим получать данные.

Кроме того, как и говорилось выше, при соединении надо сказать PDO, чтобы он сообщал об ошибках запросов. Для этого четвертым параметром передается массив с настройками (в который можно включить и другие полезные опции)

```
<?php

$options = [
    \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, // сообщать об ошибках
    \PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, // чтобы не писать каждый раз
    \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false, // для удобства
];

$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=kinoplay;charset=utf8mb4';
$pdo = new \PDO($dsn, 'root', '', $options);
```

#### 2. Извлечение данных при помощи PDO

```
<?php
require_once("connect.php");
$query = "SELECT * FROM catalog";
$cat = $pdo->query($query);
while($catalog = $cat->fetch()) {
    echo $catalog['name']."<br />";
}
```

**больше ничего писать не нужно**.  В том числе код для вывода ошибки. Не для каждой скрочки писать отдельный обработчик ошибок, РНР прекрасно умеет выводить ошибки самостоятельно.